# Как проигрывать звук из mp4 видео?

Tags: java, аудио, видео

Каким образом можно проиграть звуковую дорожку видеофайла (mp4) при помощи java?
И как её можно остановить/поставить на паузу/перескочить на определённое время?
(Что-то вроде простенького плеера)